# Reuse a Doctrine_Record object to save multiple instances of a model

Tags: symfony1, save, reusability, doctrine-collection

I am working on some kind of notifications module in a Symfony application. I am iterating over a `Doctrine_Collection` of users to create a `Notification` for every user that has a flag active in its profile:

```
// Create and define common values of notification
$notification = new Notification();
$notification->setField1('...');
$notification->setField2('...');
...

// Post notification to users
foreach ( sfGuardUserTable::getInstance()->findByNotifyNewOrder(true) as $user ) {
  $notification->setUserId($user->getId());
  $notification->save();
}
```

Problem is that once I have saved the first notification I cannot reuse the object to store new records in the database. I have tried `$notification->setId()` with `null` and `''`, but saving updates the object instead of saving a new.

Is there a way to reuse the `$notification` object? I would like to do that because logic of notification fields creation is a bit complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copy](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/ru/component-overview%3arecord%3agetting-object-copy) is what you're looking for.

```
// Create and define common values of notification
$notification = new Notification();
$notification->setField1('...');
$notification->setField2('...');
...

// Post notification to users
foreach ( sfGuardUserTable::getInstance()->findByNotifyNewOrder(true) as $user ) {
  $newNotification = $notification->copy();
  $newNotification->setUserId($user->getId());
  $newNotification->save();
}
```